# Session dependent Install/Update module

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that Install/Update some modules. If you run the script for the first time, the required modules are installed and every other times they are updated. During every update I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: The version '2.2.16' of module 'VSSetup' is currently in use. Retry the operation after closing the
```

applications.

Is there some management that I have to look into to get rid of this issue while executing the script?
This script will be executed on a regular basis inside a container and not sure how to manage session inside the script. Some reference example would be helpful. Here goes the code :

```
function Install-Update-Modules
{
[CmdletBinding()]
[OutputType([Boolean])]
Param([parameter(Mandatory)]$ModuleList)

begin { $i = 0}

process 
{
    #get the list of modules to be installed as a pre-requisite
    $modules = Get-Content -Path $ModuleList

    foreach($module in $modules)
    {
        $i = $i+1

        #check if the module is already installed or not
        $installed = Get-InstalledModule -name $module -AllVersions

        if($installed -eq $null)
        {                
            Write-Progress -Activity "Installing $($module) ...." -Status "Progress: " -PercentComplete ($i/$modules.Count*100)

            if(!(Find-Module -Name $module | Install-Module -Force -AllowClobber -Scope AllUsers))
            {
                Write-Host "Failed Installing Module $($module)" -ForegroundColor Red

                $false
            }
        }
        else
        {                
            Write-Progress -Activity "Updating $($module) ...." -Status "Progress: " -PercentComplete ($i/$modules.Count*100)

            Update-Module -Name $module -Scope AllUsers -Force
        }     
    }

    $true        
}
```

}

Comment: Do not call the function from _Visual Studio_. Call it  from `powershell -NoProfile` session.

Comment: it is never called from Visual Studio. Starting powershell command line as admin, locating to the path where the script is located and then calling by script name